# What does 'make localmodconfig' do?

Tags: linux-kernel

What does `make localmodconfig` do and what should you set so that external hardware is supported?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you precise it?

Answer (score 19):

From the [kernel README](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/README?id=refs/tags/v4.3.3):

> "make localmodconfig" Create a config based on current config and
>                              loaded modules (lsmod). Disables any module
>                              option that is not needed for the loadedmodules.
>
> To create a localmodconfig for another machine,
>                              store the lsmod of that machine into a file
>                              and pass it in as a LSMOD parameter.
>
> ```
>                target$ lsmod > /tmp/mylsmod
>                target$ scp /tmp/mylsmod host:/tmp
>
>                host$ make LSMOD=/tmp/mylsmod localmodconfig
> ```
>
> The above also works when cross compiling.
>
> ```
>  "make localyesconfig" Similar to localmodconfig, except it will convert
>                        all module options to built in (=y) options.
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure that all modules you will ever need are loaded at the point you run `make localmodconfig`. One tool that can help to achieve this is https://github.com/graysky2/modprobed-db.

First, boot up a default distribution kernel and run `/usr/bin/modprobed-db store` periodically, or every time you connect some new piece of hardware.

Then, run `sudo /usr/bin/modprobed-db recall` which will load all the modules that were ever loaded when `modprobe-db store` was run, and now you do `make localmodconfig`.