# Is there any tool to generate kernel .config file?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I watched a clip on customizing kernel, rebuilding, installing, etc. where the gentleman suggested to use an existing `.config` file with `make menuconfig` or `make xconfig`. I wanted to use one that comes with Arch BUT it's huge, it's almost 10,000 lines in it!

After summarizing those lines, it looks like there're 314 main sections (eg, `Memory Debugging`, `Android`, `Heart Rate Monitors`, `Humidity sensors`, `Magnetometer sensors`, etc.) with one or more parameters and arguments (eg. `=y`, `=m`, `#... not set` and `=number/string`). Altogether there're 2,344 entries with `=y` (statically built?), 5,159 have `=m` (loadable modules?), 163 have `=number/string` and the rest 627 are `# ... not set`.

`make localmodconfig` does a good job in reducing number of modules (`=m`) substantially BUT selects a lot of things, by default, that a machine doesn't actually have on it. For example:

Under `Input Device Drivers` section:

```
CONFIG_INPUT_TOUCHSCREEN=y
CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_PROPERTIES=y
CONFIG_INPUT_TABLET=y
CONFIG_INPUT_JOYSTICK=y
```

Under `Processor type and features`:

```
CONFIG_X86_AMD_PLATFORM_DEVICE=y
CONFIG_CPU_SUP_AMD=y
CONFIG_X86_MCE_AMD=y
```

Under `Performance monitoring`:

```
CONFIG_MICROCODE_AMD=y
CONFIG_AMD_MEM_ENCRYPT=y
CONFIG_AMD_NUMA=y
```

Under `Distributed Switch Architecture drivers`, there're 64 `=y`, it includes all vendors available? I don't have any of those and probably there're many more under other sections.

With `make localmodconfig`, I get 183 sections instead of 314 and altogether there're 1,562 `=y`, 172 `=m`, 95 `=number/string` and 2,783 `# ... not set`!

I don't need all those for sure BUT it'd be really painful to check or uncheck things manually! Is there any tool that'd scan my hardwares and generate a config file for rebuilding kernel and modules?

Comment: What exactly is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does 'make localmodconfig' do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253245/what-does-make-localmodconfig-do)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253245/what-does-make-localmodconfig-do might be a good start. From there you could use `make menuconfig` to fine-tune your kernel.

Comment: @ilkkachu, just wondering if there's any automation tool that configures kernel specifically for a device.

Comment: `localmodconfig` is the answer: you need to have a kernel with all bells and whistles running to be able to take out the bells and whistles you don't need. **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯**

Comment: @Fabby, could you please explain the process of turning all bells and whistles on and post it as an answer so that the interested one like me can understand the proper way to do it. The one I've downloaded from kernel.org to work with is `longterm 4.19.62` and the one running on the machine was downloaded during the Arch instalation process. `uname -r` returns `4.19.61-1-lts`.