# match Linux kernel config option to specific module

Tags: linux, kernel-modules

I have enabled a number of config options on a machine in order to take advantage of the [newly-included](https://www.marksei.com/wireguard-prepares-join-linux-kernel-5-6/) `wireguard` module in [Linux 5.6.0-rc1](https://github.com/torvalds/linux).

This was somewhat laborious: I had a minimal working config and guided by the errors I received while trying to put up the `wireguard` network interface I had to enable, one by one, kernel config options I was not familiar with, until `wireguard` worked (options like, say, `CONFIG_IP_NF_MANGLE`).

I now want to automate the replication of this process on another machine as much as possible. That other laptop, in turn, has a relatively small custom-configured kernel; it is an entirely different machine, so [`make localmodconfig`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253245/what-does-make-localmodconfig-do) on the *current* machine is not really an option, because I would then somehow have to merge the two configs anyway.

**What I would like to achieve**

I would like to have a process that takes a module name as input, as listed by `lsmod` (e.g. `iptable_mangle`) and gives me back the kernel option(s) relevant to enabling it (presumably `CONFIG_IP_NF_MANGLE=m` in this case?).

I have tried

- grepping for the kernel module `iptable_mangle` in the Linux source (`github` clone) in the hope of maybe finding something that links it to the corresponding kernel option;
- running `modinfo <target module name>` on the current machine, hoping that the displayed info would mention the kernel config option.

Neither of these works: the output doesn't mention `CONFIG_IP_NF_MANGLE` in either case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! I believe I have found something reasonably reliable.

Poking around through the Linux tree *after* configuring and grepping recursively for my module name (e.g. `iptable_raw` or `xt_addrtype` or what have you) always produces, among the many matching lines, exactly one of the form

```
<whatever>/Makefile:obj-$(<RELEVANT KERNEL CONFIG OPTION>) += <module name>.o`
```

Concretely, running

```
grep -rE '\+\=\s*nf_defrag_ipv6'
```

in the root of the source tree produces

```
net/ipv6/netfilter/Makefile:obj-$(CONFIG_NF_DEFRAG_IPV6) += nf_defrag_ipv6.o
```

This tells me that`CONFIG_NF_DEFRAG_IPV6` is the kernel option that enables `nf_defrag_ipv6`.

I have tried this on multiple modules, and there's always a unique line of this form returned by `grep`. This seems eminently scriptable now, to produce, roughly speaking, a hash with

- module names returned by `lsmod` as keys
- matching kernel config options as values

---

**Edit:**

A word on documentation: the above pattern was, in principle, discoverable through grepping as described, but what actually tipped me off was the `+= <object file name>` syntax mentioned in the [Kconfig documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/kconfig-language.html), which I was perusing for inspiration.

Comment: As a note, I was able to get it to do what I needed with `find /usr/src/linux/ -name "Makefile" -exec grep "CONFIG_<whichever config set as a module>" {} \;` which got all the modules I needed for Docker except for CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_MASQUERADE.  Going the other way, I think it would just be `find /usr/src/linux -name "Makefile" -exec grep " += <module file name>" {} \;`